# Shortest path using HashMaps and ArrayList (using BFS)

Tags: arraylist, hashmap, shortest-path, breadth-first-search

I'm trying to find the shortest path of finding friends. If person X wants to connect to person Y, I want to print out the shortest path of friends in order for X to get to Y. Everytime I run the code, I get null as a result.

public void shortest(String first, String target){

```
    HashMap<String, String> prev = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Queue<PersonNode> q = new LinkedList<PersonNode>();
    PersonNode firstPerson = hash.get(first);

    firstPerson.visited = true;
    prev.put(first, first + " ");
    q.add(firstPerson);

    while(!q.isEmpty()){    
        PersonNode curr = q.remove();

        if(!curr.visited){
            curr.visited = true;
            if(curr.equals(target)){
                break;
            }
            else{
                for(int i =0; i < curr.list.size(); i++){
                    if(curr.list.get(i).visited = false){
                        q.add(curr.list.get(i));
                        curr.list.get(i).visited = true;
                        prev.put(curr.list.get(i).name, prev.get(curr.list.get(i).name) + curr.list.get(i));

                    }
                }

            }
            if(!curr.equals(target)){
                System.out.println("They have no connections");
            }

        }
    }
    System.out.println(prev.get(target));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try debugging your code**. I see you set `firstperson.visited` to `true` outside of the loop. You then pop it from you queue and ignore it because it's `true`. It's the same inside your loop: you set all visited attributes to true which will cause them to be ignored when they get popped from the queue at runtime

I'm also thinking that the "they have no connections"-part should not be inside the while loop